# JQuery filter on select input with mouse doesn't work

Tags: jquery, firefox, select, filter, onclick

I am a bit of a newbie at this jQuery/java stuff. I have trawled a lot of hint pages on here and other sites and most of my code works but I have an issue I have not been able to overcome so far.

What I want is a cascading series of select elements that change the values available in following select elements etc. The final select is a menu option whereby the user can chosse from a list of standard menus (populated via a jquery filter based on the previous select choices made) or from a text box which has an autocomplete list of available menu options.

All of the data and options get rendered correctly, the only issue is that the last select element can only be accessed via keyboard, I cannot click on it with a mouse and select one of the options.

I suspect that it is somethoing with conflicting java "handlers" on the same "onclick" event, but I have exhausted my limited knowledge in figuring it out.

I tried for help on the mozilla forums but haven't had much luck.
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2941553

The filter part of the JS is below but see http://jsfiddle.net/gcraill/woss5huL/ for full code.

```
$("#busarea").change(function() { 
    var id = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).data('options') == undefined){
        $(this).data('options',$('#stdmenu option').clone());
    } 
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[data-bu=' + id + ']');
    $('#stdmenu').html(options);
    if (id == "X"){ 
        document.forms["trntestform"]["menutype"].style.visibility='hidden';
        document.forms['trntestform']['menutype'].value = 'X';
    } else {
        document.forms["trntestform"]["menutype"].style.visibility='visible';
    }
    $("#menutype").trigger("change");
}).change();
```

I suspect my java is wonky (self taught sorry) and i don't really know how all the JQuery/java stuff ties in, so any tips that can help fix this on our old FF release would be awesome!

Cheers
GC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of your code is what's causing the problem:

```
else {
    if (mtyp == "*STD"){ 
                document.forms["trntestform"]["stdmenu"].style.visibility='visible';
                document.forms["trntestform"]["othmenu"].style.visibility='hidden';
            }
            if (mtyp == "*OTH"){ 
                document.forms["trntestform"]["stdmenu"].style.visibility='hidden';
                document.forms["trntestform"]["othmenu"].style.visibility='visible';
            }
    }
```

The `visibility` style doesn't remove the element from the screen, it just makes them invisible.  This div here:

```
<div class='toggle'><input type='text' name='othmenu' id='othmenu' placeholder='Start typing a menu name' size='25' maxlength='11' style='visibility: hidden;' /></div>
```

is actually always on top of the stdmenu dropdown list, so you can't click it because there's a textbox (secretly) on top of it.  If you want to actually hide the elements so they're not on top of each other, try doing this instead:

```
else {
    document.forms["trntestform"]["stdmenu"].style.visibility='visible';
    document.forms["trntestform"]["othmenu"].style.visibility='visible';
        if (mtyp == "*STD"){ 
                        document.forms["trntestform"]["stdmenu"].style.display='block';
                        document.forms["trntestform"]["othmenu"].style.display='none';
                    }
                    if (mtyp == "*OTH"){ 
                        document.forms["trntestform"]["stdmenu"].style.display='none';
                        document.forms["trntestform"]["othmenu"].style.display='block';
                    }
    }
```

You may have to tweak your styling, but that will let your dropdown be clickable.

Comment: Awesome shall investigate that line of thought ... thought it was likely my wonky java skillz :)   ---> But could I retain the visibility (as that preserves the width of the items) and instead alter the z-index so the other one is on the top?

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with the z-index as well.  Without changing your HTML, the textbox is higher, so you could just flip-flop the z-index with the visibility change

Comment: Thanks Johnathan, I used the display none|block and altered the css so that it preserved the cell sizes, works perfectly now!   ~ GC

Comment: I might add, days on the FF forums at mozilla and sod all help, hours here and presto   --  Very Nice!